# Where can I see all my friends on lichess?

Tags: lichess

I'm not sure if it's called friends or just users I am following. When I press on my profile there's a section which allows me to see the users that are following me but I'm looking for the one's I'm following in a list. I can also just search the username and it suggests them from the drop down search bar but I'm looking for a list of all of them. Maybe someone knows where it is or if there's a URL that can get me there?

Answer (score 5):

When you go to followers there's a button for following.

I also found the URL:

> https://lichess.org/@/USERNAME/following